# NSURL found nil while unwraping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Anyone knows why am I getting

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When i use

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907")!
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `|` character its not a valid URL character so you must replace it with percent escape character. Encoding whole string will do that automatically for you

```
var stringUrl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907"

let URL = NSURL(string: stringUrl.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
```

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated. Use  `stringUrl .stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`

Comment: @ayteq I'm trying to use this as well... but it seems it just doesn't want to append

Comment: @user805981 Very strange! When you copy the code from my comment, it includes a special character which is not seen in Xcode. So please use auto-complete option in Xcode. Please see the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxvnyocz/) I can't edit my comment, sorry about that.

Comment: @zell B . I want to implement snap to roads Can u guide how to achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4**

I was trying with :

```
https://api.url.com/method?token=abcdfghijklmopqrst&command=>SSSXP10<&otherParam=12345678
```

And the '**>**' and '**<**' characters was giving me the error.

For the solution :

```
let objectUrl = URL(string:url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, It's a crazy issue. Because of **<** and **>** it was giving an error

```
let username = searchTextFileld.text!
let urlString: String = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=\(username)+repos:>100+followers:>100"
```