# Found nil NSURL POSt request Swift

Tags: swift, post

In my POST request , my URL throws an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. This is what it looks like:

```
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://88.143.30.77/app_backend/public/api/v1/image?_r={rec_id}")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

If I remove the "?_r={rec_id}" part in the URL, the error goes away, but I have no idea how to fix it, because that's the URL I need to send my image to.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That URL is invalid because it cannot contain `{` and `}`. You will have to encode the query parameters first.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `{rec_id}` should be replaced with an actual value. You should have something like this:

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://88.143.30.77/app_backend/public/api/v1/image?_r=123456")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

Documentation often uses angled brackets or curly braces to indicate where a value should be inserted. The angled brackets or curly braces themselves, along with the placeholder value, are what is replaced.

Comment: You should tell the OP how to interpolate strings, like `"\(myValue)"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix here: [NSURL found nil while unwraping an Optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882954/nsurl-found-nil-while-unwraping-an-optional-value) .

I needed to encode the whole string

Comment: Is `rec_id` not a value you need to put into the URL?

Comment: Also do yourself a favor by using `if let` or `guard` to handle other potential `nil` `NSURL` return values instead of crashing again.