# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value WKWebView get parameters

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

im working on WKWebView and when i load a url without parameters like this it works fine

```
func loadAddress(lat:Double,lng:Double){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://url.com/dev2/billboard/geo")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    webview.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

but i want to send user's location with get parameters like this

```
func loadAddress(lat:Double,lng:Double){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://url.com/dev2/billboard/geo/\(lat)/\(lng)")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    webview.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

it shows this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-02-02 16:43:36.645898 pixel[5112:1996136] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

thanks is advance

Comment: If the first function works, then there is issue with the requestURL. In case of second function, check the url exists or not trying to load it in safari browser of iPhone.

Comment: Can you step through your function and please check what value is getting `nil`? Is it `requestURL`? And try to use the new versions of the API without the NS prefixes.

Answer (score 8):

Try to encode your url and use Swift native type [`URL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) and [`URLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlrequest) instead of `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest`.

```
let stringUrl = "http://url.com/dev2/billboard/geo/\(lat)/\(lng)"
if let encodedURL = stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
   let url = URL(string: encodedURL) {
      webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

**Edit:** I have tried url that you have added in comment it is showing perfectly when you encode it with `urlQueryAllowed`. May be you have not added `NSAppTransportSecurity` with your `info.plist` file try to add once and it will works for you too.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I was thinking almost the same that the doubles injected into the URL mess up the URL format and therefore URL(string:) return nil.

Comment: when i print(url.absoluteString) the url it shows is correct but the problem is still same

Comment: It should be the same. Because you need to check the url if its correct or not. I had the same issue just a week ago @WasifKhalil

Comment: @WasifKhalil Try once `.urlPathAllowed` and `.urlHostAllowed` encoding also.

Comment: @WasifKhalil Also is your url valid? Have you check on browser as Jason suggested?

Comment: im now guessing the problem is something else because i tried to pass string in a hardcoded url and the problem is same? what could be wrong? like this http://url.com/dev2/billboard/geo/abc/def

Comment: my url with lat lng in the log is valid, i have checked it in browser

Comment: @WasifKhalil Have you tried with `.urlPathAllowed` and `.urlHostAllowed` once?

Comment: @WasifKhalil got 404 for this http://lyrics.url.com/dev2/billboard/geo/abc/def   url.

Comment: .urlHostAllowed messed up by url like this "http:%2F%2Fmigapixel.com%2Fdev2%2Fbillboard%2Fgeo%2F24.8212602082871%2F67.0793047361701" and with urlPathAllowed the url was correct but still didnt work

Comment: @JasonBourne the actual url is http://migapixel.com/dev2/billboard/geo/24.8211901802791/67.0792666255154

Comment: @WasifKhalil does the above url works with your code?

Comment: yes it works on browser http://migapixel.com/dev2/billboard/geo/24.8211901802791/67.0792666255154

Comment: yes it does not even work hardcoded whoever  migapixel.com/dev2/billboard/geo this works fine without error on ios but i need to send location

Comment: tried hardcoded but doesnt work like this, let url = URL(string: "http://migapixel.com/dev2/billboard/geo/24.8211679235332/67.0792313945173")

Comment: @WasifKhalil I have tried with the url that you given with `urlQueryAllowed` like my answer, First it will not show anything after that I have add `App Transport Security Settings` in `info.plist` file and it is showing perfectly in my simulator check this image also https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUIcl.png If you doesn't add `Transport Security Settings` in plist try to add and it will works for you too

Comment: i already added Transport Security Settings, said i said it works without parameters

Comment: @WasifKhalil It is perfectly working for me url that you have added with lat long this one http://migapixel.com/dev2/billboard/geo/24.8211679235332/67.0792313945173 You can check this simulator image of my https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUIcl.png

Comment: @NiravD yes i believe you but for some reason it doesnt work for me and im scratching my head :S i was trying on my phone, going to try simulator now

Comment: @WasifKhalil Ok, And Are you still using `urlQueryAllowed` encoding like my answer right?

Comment: Thanks! the same problem/answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909990/5869217)